# HttpPost и пароль

Tags: http, мобильные-приложения

Пользователь в мобильном приложении вводит пароль. На стороне клиента он хешируется до вида, как в БД, потом ещё как-то хешируется с переменной солью для передачи на сервер для проверки. Затем, вместе с данными, по которым построится эта самая переменная соль, передаётся на сервер в теле HttpPost запроса по Https.

Храню пароль в БД в виде некоторого хэша с постоянной солью. При получении запроса он извлекается из БД, с помощью полученных данных строится переменная соль, хэшируется и сравнивается с тем, что передал пользователь.

Является ли эта методика безопасной и на сколько?

Comment: "потом ещё как-то хешируется" то есть вы сами не знаете, что происходит?

Comment: @Zergatul, ну конечно я знаю. Имеется ввиду какая-то стандартная хеш-функция, которая выполняется n раз. Для данного вопроса это не важно.